# IOS Calculate number of weeks between dates

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

It is known to calculate the number of years, days, months using NSCalenderUnit type between two days using

```
dateComponent = [calender components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];

totalDays = (int)dateComponent.day;
```

Anyone suggest How to get total number of weeks?
I have tried using available week units but not met with requirement.

Note: we cant use totaldays / 7.. since If startdate = jan'10'2015 endDate Feb' 02'15 means 22/7 = 3 but actually it is 4.. (Jan 2nd, 3rd,4th week and Feb 1st week.)

Comment: How did you fail? What's the problem? What's the code you used?

Comment: which calendar unit need to be used. tried with NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear and others return wrong values. For one year input need to return 52. but these returns 9312121.. like output

Comment: Use int weeks = (totalDays/7) is number of weeks between dates

Comment: no we cant say totaldays/7..  If it startdate = jan'10'2015 endDate Feb' 02'15 means 22/7 = 3 but actually it is  4.. (Jan 2nd, 3rd,4th week and Feb 1st week.)

Comment: do u want to calculate weeks between dates?

Comment: Try using [dateComponents weekOfYear]